# Determine which textbox to update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

EDIT: Made the problem easier.

Model

```
public class Human
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class HumanViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Human human;
    public HumanViewModel()
    {
        human = new Human();
    }

    public string TxtHumanName
    {
        get => Human.Name;
        set
        {
            Human.Name = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void InvokePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In my XAML i need 2 texboxes i.e

Human1: [   ]  <-- humanName1txtBox

Human2: [   ]  <-- humanName2txtBox

In my xaml.cs file I will create Task which will be assigning human a name. (as i understand this kind of code should be somewhere else).

```
public Task SetName(HumanViewModel humanVM, string name)
    {
        humanVM.TxtHumanName = name;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Imagine running this Task Set Name multiple times. How can I assign it so that first time it will update humanName1txtBox and second time humanName2txtBox

Comment: Hi this is just a comment So what I can understand is you have 2 task running in xaml.cs and 2 Vm s with names Nest1 and 2 and need to update a single text box in ui if you are using code behind then you can directly use the name to change the text or if you wanna use mvvm this is not the way to do it, if you still wanna do it u can change datacontext of view so its reflect which i won't suggest

Comment: Yes, it's easy to bind one textbox to certain property and use MVVM that way. But problem is when i.e using 8 textboxes and this same property is used but each Task will make an instance out of that ViewModel class. How to bind so that each task will make changes to only it's textbox.

Comment: I don't follow why you appear to be using mvvm but then decide to do processing from the view. The "obvious" answer is to await an async task in each row's viewmodel.  It then is changing any property in "this".

Comment: @Andy Can you give me an brief example? So all the business logic should be done in viewModel and how to assing each row a textbox.

Comment: I haven't seen the xaml code but this sounds like a perfect candidate for `DataTemplate`. Each task would be represented in the view (you can then have as many as you want) and then update the property in ViewModel, Binding will then update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

When you have repeated things then you should be thinking in terms of an itemscontrol and templating items into UI.

Bind an itemssource to an observablecollection rowvm where rowvm is viewmodel per row. That is templated into a textbox or whatever you need and your logic goes in rowvm. It therefore "knows" what to update because it's itself.

Very simple introduction article to MVVM. You would want something more sophisticated than just a string for your row viewmodel:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Not sure exactly what you want to do but you would have something like:

```
public rowVM : BaseViewModel
{
    private Task<result> doSomething
     {
       …..
     }
    public string WhateverYourTextIs  // propfull
}
```

Each is templated into a row in your view.

Whenever you want to do your process you start up that Task and await it. That returns a result and you do whatever you're doing with that result.